# How to identify which characters are mismatching in a user input string

Tags: java, palindrome

This project is used to identify whether or not a user's input is a palindrome, and if it's not, identifies how many characters don't match and their positions in the string (i.e characters 2 and 4 don't match). I've been able to figure out how to identify whether or not a string is a palindrome, but I'm struggling with how to specifically identify the characters that don't match in a non-palindrome. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      
      String stringInput = "";
      String inputReverse = "";
      
      boolean isPalindrome = true;
      
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
      stringInput = keyboard.nextLine();
      
      
      int stringLength = stringInput.length();
      
      for(int i = stringLength - 1; i >=0; i--)
      {
        inputReverse = inputReverse + stringInput.charAt(i);
      }
      
      if(stringInput.equals(inputReverse))
      {
         System.out.println(stringInput + " is a valid palindrome.");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println(stringInput + " is not a valid palindrome.");
      }
   }
}
```

the output I want for when a string is not a palindrome is:
"The characters at index 0 and 3 do not match.
goop is not a valid palindrome.
number of invalid character matches: 1 "

I tried to use stringInput.charAt(0) but the user input is unpredictable, so I wouldn't be able to use char 0,1,2,3 etc forever. Any help?

Comment: A `char` in Java is a primitive. It is a type of integer. So, you can use [relational operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)  on them. Where you have `inputString.charAt(0)`, instead of `0`, use an `int` variable, which you can get from a `for` loop index.  (By the way, you can do arithmetic with `char`,)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate from both ends of the string, moving toward the center and checking the corresponding characters each time.

```java
int nomatch = 0;
for (int i = 0, j = stringLength - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    if (stringInput.charAt(i) != stringInput.charAt(j)) {
        ++nomatch;
        System.out.format("The characters at index %d and %d do not match.%n", i, j);
    }
}
if (nomatch == 0) System.out.println(stringInput + " is a palindrome.");
else System.out.println(stringInput + " is not a palindrome. Number of invalid character matches: " + nomatch);
```

Comment: You think you're helping by providing code for a homework assignment, but doing so robs OP of a valuable learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

As this is [home work](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166), I'll only give general hints:

- an easy way to reverse a string is `inputReverse = new StringBuilder(stringInput).reverse().toString();`
- you only need to compare each character of the first *half* of the input with its reverse
- use a `for` loop of `int` from 0 to half the length and pass it to `charAt()` for both strings and compare using `==`
- store the indexes of differences in a `List<Integer>`